# Easy way to copy swf activity settings for version update?

Tags: version, flash, amazon-swf

All I originally wanted was to add a few new activities to the existing version.

```
BuyAppleActivity.pickAppleInOrganicSection   1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:06 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.pickAppleInNormalSection  1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:06 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.getWallet    1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:08 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.putDownAppleInOrganicSection   1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:06 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.putDownAppleInNormalSection  1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:07 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.pay    1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:08 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.takeOutWallet  1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:08 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.getChange   1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:06 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.unputDownAppleInOrganicSection 1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:07 GMT-700 2015
BuyAppleActivity.unputDownAppleInNormalSection    1/23/2015   Fri May 29 12:37:06 GMT-700 2015
SellAppleActivity.pickApple 1/23/2015   Fri Jun 12 13:49:34 GMT-700 2015
SellAppleActivity.putAppleInBag  1/23/2015   Mon Jun 15 09:20:44 GMT-700 2015 <-------------- I just added this activity
SellAppleActivity.putDownApple 1/23/2015   Fri Jun 12 13:50:13 GMT-700 2015
SellAppleActivity.takePayment  1/23/2015   Fri Jun 12 13:34:06 GMT-700 2015
SellAppleActivity.giveChange    1/23/2015   Fri Jun 12 13:52:45 GMT-700 2015
SellAppleActivity.unputDownApple   1/23/2015   Fri Jun 12 13:50:42 GMT-700 2015
```

Of course I screwed up.....

Now I find myself needing to update the version of all activities to "06/18/2015" without changing any other settings. Now I have to **manually copy all but the activity that I screwed up on**. Since this is manually being copied, I doubt I won't make any mistake.

I wonder if there is a more customer friendly way of **copying a subset of the existing activities while bumping the version number**?

Comment: What language are you using? Using any swf ask?

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not required to update versions of all activities if only one of them is changed.